# How to fix Module not found: Can't resolve './store'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm setting up a React Redux with a Provider but it always comes back with an error message saying that ./store not being found. What I'm doing wrong here? and What do I need to set up in index.js file?

This is first I have looked at the React.js Redux website to tried to set up Provider and setup react-cookies.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './sass/main.scss';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
import store from './store'

const rootElement = document.getElementById('cantainer')

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CookiesProvider>
      <App />,
      rootElement
    </CookiesProvider>
  </Provider>
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './sass/main.scss';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
import store from './store'

const rootElement = document.getElementById('cantainer')

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CookiesProvider>
      <App />,
      rootElement
    </CookiesProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```

This is error message: 
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './store' in '/Users/mirasmith/Desktop/KPV1-Project-master/src'

Comment: You will need to share the contents of `store/index.js` file to further assistance.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Okay, So I have to do like this `./store/index.js

Comment: You don’t usually need to specify index.js, I meant the actual contents of the file to make sure you are exporting things correct.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky So, I have change but still say cannot be found. ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'store/index.js'

Comment: Show content of the `./store`

Comment: Please copy and paste the contents of the file into the question. Your import is fine, most likely something Is wrong inside the file.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Something wrong with my file or React-Redux.

Comment: Something could be wrong with the contents of the file. Copy and paste the code inside the file into your question. I’m not sure how many different remaining ways that can be asked.

Comment: Nope, please put it into the body of the question, don’t link to outside sources.

Comment: I'm sorry little confused what question you're talking about to copy? Are you talking the code at the copy that or error message?

Comment: `import store from './store'` <-- this line means that there must be a `store.js` or a `store/index.js` in the same folder as the file you've pasted.  The error is telling you that it cannot find any such file.

Comment: @Brandon Your saying that I have to create a file called store.js but what goes inside that file.

Comment: review whatever tutorial or documentation you are following to get you this far.  It should show how to create the actual redux store.

Comment: if you are not following a tutorial, then you should go through this one: https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial

Comment: Thank you @Brandon So, I have one more question. So, Everything in docs will go inside of the store.js file

Comment: nope.  That tutorial walks you through creating `actions.js` `reducers.js` and `store.js`

Comment: Please see the Redux docs page on [Configuring Your Store](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store).